# Função para ir para uma determinada parte do código

Tags: r

Há alguma função no R para que o dada uma condição ele pule para determinada parte do código. Estou implementando um modelo de auditoria, porém em determinados pontos ele precisa de arquivos externos que são enviados somente no final do ano, mas gostaria de analisar os outros itens antes disso. O código que pensei seria algo parecido com o de baixo, mas não o uqe inserir dentro do `if`.

```
if(length(list.files(pattern = "RREO"))==0){#Proximo item da auditoria}
```

Comment: Creio que deve pensar em mudar a lógica do código. `if(o ficheiro existe){processar ficheiro} else {seguir em frente}`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `next`. Veja exemplo fictício:

```
v <- LETTERS[1:6]
for ( i in v) {

   if (i == "D") {
      next
   }
   print(i)
}
[1] "A" 
[1] "B" 
[1] "C" 
[1] "E" 
[1] "F"
```

No seu caso o `v` seriam os arquivos, e vc faria a condição baseado se o arquivo existe ou não (ou seja, se ele retorna `NULL` na importação).